# Eclipse Ease - ReferenceError: "loadModule" is not defined

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We are using Eclipse ease in a Eclipse Plugin application, and after updating from 0.6 to 0.8 We are having the following errors.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.help.base 4 0 2021-07-29 05:29:13.360
!MESSAGE Help cannot be displayed.  The embedded application server could not run help web application.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.server.JettyHelpServer.checkBundle(JettyHelpServer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.server.JettyHelpServer.start(JettyHelpServer.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.server.WebappManager.start(WebappManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.base.BaseHelpSystem.ensureWebappRunning(BaseHelpSystem.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.base.BaseHelpSystem.resolve(BaseHelpSystem.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.DefaultHelpUI.resolve(DefaultHelpUI.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.help.WorkbenchHelpSystem.resolve(WorkbenchHelpSystem.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.help.hovers.ModuleHelp.getModuleHelpLocation(ModuleHelp.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.view.ModuleExplorerView$3.getContent(ModuleExplorerView.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.view.ModuleExplorerView$3.getContent(ModuleExplorerView.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.help.hovers.internal.ControlHoverManager$3.run(ControlHoverManager.java:142)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ease.ui 4 0 2021-07-29 05:29:13.410
!MESSAGE Cannot find the module help content 
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1165)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.help.hovers.ModuleHelp.getHtmlContent(ModuleHelp.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.help.hovers.ModuleHelp.<init>(ModuleHelp.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.view.ModuleExplorerView$3.getContent(ModuleExplorerView.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.view.ModuleExplorerView$3.getContent(ModuleExplorerView.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.ease.ui.help.hovers.internal.ControlHoverManager$3.run(ControlHoverManager.java:142)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.ease.debugging.model.EaseDebugValue (file:/home/saul/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ease_0.8.0.I202105061131.jar) to field java.lang.Throwable.depth
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.ease.debugging.model.EaseDebugValue
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

And also inside the rhino interpreter/console we get the following.

> loadModule('/System/Environment');    ReferenceError: "loadModule" is
> not defined.

What could we missing? Application compiles successfully and the Eclipse Ease plugins are listed in the Installation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EASE is not working with eclipse 2021-03 target platform due to [bug 571990](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571990)